# Why does my comparison model using anova fails to produce a P-value in certain cases?

Tags: logistic, anova

I am trying to run a logistic regression using the brglm library. My outcome variable is cohort membership and predictor variables are different biochemical analytes. I am comparing my brglm model to a reduced model using anova by the LRT test. I have noticed certain cases where the anova model fails to produce a P-value, can someone please explain why this is happening and if there is a way to fix this? Appreciate all your responses and comments.

I am adding two test cases below, in the first case the model produces a pvalue but for the second case it fails.

```
 model <- brglm(cohort ~ intensity, data=mydata, family=binomial)
 ann_model <- anova(brglm(cohort ~1,data=mydata,family=binomial),model,test='LRT')
```

Case1:

```
  intensity       cohort
  3.982803        0
  3.709617        1
  4.112124        0
  3.641153        1
  3.901170        0
  4.009892        0
  3.870631        0
  3.839631        0
  3.781422        1
  3.990825        0
  3.861698        0
  3.803384        0
  3.943502        1
  3.713851        1
  3.770408        0
  3.795767        1
  3.853228        0
  3.959088        0
```

print(model)

```
  Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)   50.092     26.325   1.903   0.0571 .
intensity    -13.216      6.884  -1.920   0.0549 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

 Null deviance: 18.044  on 17  degrees of freedom
 Residual deviance: 15.246  on 16  degrees of freedom
 Penalized deviance: 18.05726 
 AIC:  19.246
```

print(ann_model)

```
 Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: cohort ~ 1
Model 2: cohort ~ intensity
   Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance Pr(>Chi)   
 1        17     22.921                        
 2        16     15.246  1   7.6743 0.005601 **
```

Case2:

```
intensity       cohort
5.333070        0
5.768164        1
5.672163        0
5.837189        1
5.795308        0
5.662572        0
5.825039        0
5.791632        0
5.534392        1
5.622307        0
5.673980        0
5.804462        0
5.738737        1
5.628145        1
5.750425        0
5.694530        1
5.627113        0
5.721303        0
```

print(model)

```
    Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  -1.8156    23.8845  -0.076    0.939
intensity     0.2105     4.1936   0.050    0.960

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

  Null deviance: 18.425  on 17  degrees of freedom
  Residual deviance: 22.923  on 16  degrees of freedom
  Penalized deviance: 24.3799 
  AIC:  26.923
```

print(ann_model)

```
   Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: cohort ~ 1
Model 2: cohort ~ intensity
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df   Deviance Pr(>Chi)
1        17     22.921                       
2        16     22.923  1 -0.0022438
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proximal problem is that in the second example the estimated deviance of your null model is actually *smaller* than the estimated deviance of the full model (note that the deviance difference reported by `anova()` is negative ...). In the standard likelihood framework that should never happen (because the restricted model can't possibly fit better than the full model); one does occasionally see this happen in practice for complicated/numerically unstable models where (1) the two likelihoods are **nearly** equivalent (i.e. the full model is only a tiny bit better than the restricted model) and (2) there is some numeric error in the parameter estimation and/or deviance calculation such that the ordering flips.

Sometimes fussing with numerical tolerances and/or changing starting parameters can help, although the little bit I tried didn't make a difference.

The other possibility is that this comparison doesn't work the way you (or I) think it does in the penalized-likelihood context. `?brglm` directly warns that:

> 1. It is not advised to use methods associated with model
>       comparison (‘add1’, ‘drop1’, ‘anova’, etc.) on objects of class
>       ‘"brglm"’. Model comparison when estimation is performed using the
>       modified scores or the penalized likelihood is an on-going
>       research topic and will be implemented as soon as it is concluded.

Practically speaking, you can probably conclude that the deviances of the full and null model are very similar (within 0.005 deviance units of each other), so the model comparison is not significant at any meaningful level.